# Problema al localizar elementos de pagina que se cargan dinámicamente utilizando Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, scraping

estoy intentando scrapear la página https://magiceden.io/ordinals/marketplace/bitmap.

Estoy trabajando con Selenium en python.
Necesito obtener los elementos (#.bitmap) que van apareciendo al scrollear.
Los primeros elementos los obtengo sin problema ya que están cargados en el DOM. Mi problema aparece cuando empiezo a scrollear, ya que  la condición que establezco para localizar cada elemento en Selenium aparentemente deja de ser válida. Probé con varias condiciones y todas dan problema.
Es como que al scrollear hacia abajo, la pagina carga async los nuevos elementos y los viejos elementos desaparecen del DOM. Por lo tanto no son mas accesibles para selenium.

My código:

```html
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

magicEdenUrl = 'https://magiceden.io/ordinals/marketplace/bitmap'
ordinalsWalletUrl = 'https://ordinalswallet.com/collection/bitmap/analyzer/'
bitmapComunnityUrl = 'https://bitmap.community/analyzer/'
driver = webdriver.Edge()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
sumador = 0
nBitmaps = []
rarityRank = ''
rarityRankRequired = 50000
rango = 30
contador = 0
contador2 = 0
scroll = 100

driver.get(magicEdenUrl)


for n in range(rango):
    
    try:
        #En esta linea con xpath encuentro los elementos con div[n + 1] y los voy guardando. Cuando llega al septimo elemento se actualiza el DOM y ya no funciona.(O eso es lo que creo)
Selenium suele arrojar la excepción: Stale Element Reference Exception.

        bitmaps = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[{n + 1}]/div[2]/div/div/a')


        #bitmaps = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, f'//*[contains(text(), ".bitmap")]')
        driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0,{scroll})")
        scroll = scroll + scroll
        nBitmaps.append(bitmaps.text[:bitmaps.text.index('.')])

        contador2 = contador2 + 1 
        print(f'Anduvo: {contador2}')
    except:
        contador = contador + 1
        
        print(f'El 1er for no anduvo: {contador} veces')
        #driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0,{scroll})")
        
        #browser.close()
       


    time.sleep(1)
```

Intente otras formas: Cargo la página, la scrolleo hasta el final, guardo el contenido html, lo parseo con beautifulsoup4 y lo trato de filtrar con bs4.El problema persiste,bs4 encuentra algunos elementos y otros no.